# Is it possible to simplify the following into one row?

Tags: c#, initialization

I apologize for a really bad title. I don't know the correct terminology, but will edit it if you can inform me what I am actually asking.

Is it possible to do the following in one row, like with an auto-property?:

```
public class MyClass
{
    static OtherClass _otherClass;
    static OtherClass otherClass => _otherClass ?? (_otherClass = new OtherClass());
}
```

Comment: `static OtherClass otherClass { get; } = new OtherClass();` is roughly equivalent, if you are happy for the object to be initialised earlier.

Comment: Oh, of course. Really silly of me. I didn't realize method calls could be used when initializing fields. How can I set your answer as correct?

Comment: Yes, that post is probably much more useful to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Lazy<T>` for lazy initialization, although it does not simplify the code too much:

```
static Lazy<OtherClass> _otherClassLazy = new Lazy<OtherClass>(() => new OtherClass());

static OtherClass otherClass => _otherClassLazy.Value;
```

`Lazy<T>` initializes the value only once, and only when actually accessed.

If you really want a single line, you can use:

```
static Lazy<OtherClass> otherClass { get; } = new Lazy<OtherClass>(() => new OtherClass());
```

At the cost of having to use `otherClass.Value` when referring to this variable in code.

This solution is preferable to the `{ get; } = new OtherClass()` in case you want to initialize the property only on-demand, not during the initialization of the class itself. This may be desirable in case the constructor is doing a lot of work and the property might not be used in some cases.

Comment: The last property has to be of type Lazy<OtherClass>, no?

Comment: True that :-) ! Thanks Freggar, fixed